# How to create walking character using multiple images from sprite sheet

Tags: python, animation, pygame

I want to create the "illusion" so to speak that my character is walking, using multiple images from a sheet of multiple sprite positions. I only know how to move the single image using WASD. Here is my code so far:

```
room_bg = 'woodf.jpg'#wood floor background
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,360),0,32)

background = pygame.image.load(room_bg).convert()#background here
x,y = 290,150
movex, movey = 0,0   
while 1:#blitting background to middle of screen, start of main game loop
    screen.blit(background, (170,100))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_a:
            movex = -1
            pygame.image.load('s_left1.png')
            pygame.Surface.blit(mc_left1)
        elif event.key == K_d:
            movex = +1
        elif event.key == K_w:
            movey = -1
        elif event.key == K_s:
            movey = +1
    if event.type == KEYUP:
        if event.key == K_a:
            movex = 0
        elif event.key == K_d:
            movex = 0
        elif event.key == K_w:
            movey = 0
        elif event.key == K_s:
            movey = 0

x+= movex
y+= movey

mc = pygame.image.load('ss.png').convert()
mc.set_colorkey((0,0,0))
screen.blit(mc,(x,y))
pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

You first want to extract individual sprites from the sprite sheet, then you want to use, for example, an iterator for serving them to the drawing method in each call.

[Here you have a tutorial](http://pygame.org/wiki/Spritesheet) on how to get individual images from the sprite sheet and how to use them for animation.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is the most efficient way of animating a sprite, but it's been working for me so far.

First I load all the sprite frames into a list called **spritesheet**. Then each time a move event is triggered, I iterate through each frame, updating the display between each iteration. I also introduced a small time delay to make it look more fluid. Again, probably not the best way to do it, but it's a way.

```
 for spriteframe in spritesheet:
      x_add = x/len(spritesheet)
      y_add = y/len(spritesheet)
      player.setPosition( player.getX() + x_add, player.getY() + y_add )
      updateBackground(current_map)
      pygame.time.delay(40)
      updateCharacter(player,spriteframe, image)
      pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: I use this too but use `Clock = pygame.time.Clock()` and then `Clock.tick(25)` instead of `pygame.time.delay(40)`